# How to increase the efficiency of pyspark to pandas dataframe conversion other than PyArrow or with it

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried PyArrow as well, In my example I got the spark datframe using spark.sql statement. After which I wanted to convert to pandas dataframe. To show the excution times I ran these below statements.

```
import time
startTime = time.time()
df=df.toPandas()
executionTime = (time.time() - startTime)
executionTime
```

this gave 1021.55

I also tried

```
import time
startTime = time.time()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
df=df.toPandas()
executionTime = (time.time() - startTime)
executionTime
```

This gave 1008.71

To give  brief idea of the dataframe shape was (944,5). Below are the data types in spark dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1) # to prevent truncating of columns in jupyter

def count_column_types(spark_df):
"""Count number of columns per type"""
return pd.DataFrame(spark_df.dtypes).groupby(1, as_index=False)[0].agg({'count':'count', 'names':lambda x: " | ".join(set(x))}).rename(columns={1:"type"})
 count_column_types(df) 

    type           count    names
 0  bigint          1   col4
 1  date            1   col1
 2  decimal(20,4)   1   col5
 3  int             1   col2
 4  string          1   col3
```

Please let me know if there is any way I can increase the efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled` has effect if you're using so-called Pandas UDFs, but not in your case.

Your problem is that `toPandas` needs to collect all data from executors to the driver node, but before that, it needs to process your SQL query, and main bottleneck could be there (you didn't show example, so it's hard to say).  You can try to understand where the bottleneck is - in the SQL query execution, or it's really in `toPandas`.  To do that, try something like:

```
df = spark.sql(....)
import time
startTime = time.time()
df.write.format("noop").mode("overwrite").save()
executionTime = (time.time() - startTime)
executionTime
```

and compare this execution time with time that you get from `toPandas`.

Comment: It is throwing error at the write .format step saying Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o123.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: noop. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: ah, for that you need Spark 3... replace that line with `df.count()`, for example

Comment: The count aswell takes as much time thus realised the collection is taking more time not exactly due to pandas. Thus changing my query to be more efficient